# How to properly utilize settimeout function to rotate a cube with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, settimeout, requestanimationframe

The program I am writing will be used to rotate a cube. The html file will allow the user to input a csv file with quaternion data. Then, the javascript code rotates the cube using each quaternion in the data file at a constant rate. In this case, each new quaternion is applied to the cube every 16.7 milliseconds (60 fps). The current program I have written uses setTimeout to execute this goal.

Here is the javascript code I currently have:

```
    <script>

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff70 } );
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cube );

    camera.position.z = 5;
    renderer.render(scene,camera);


    var animate = function() {

        quat_data = [];

        var rotate = function(quat) {
          cube.applyQuaternion(quat);
        }

        for(i=0; i<quat_data.length; i++) {
            time = 16.7;
            var next_quat = quat_data[i];
            setTimeout(rotate(next_quat), time);
        }


    }



    </script>
```

The user clicks a button on the top of the browser display to execute the animate function. Also, note that quat_data is currently empty. To test the javascript code, I set quat_data equal to an array of sample quaternions. I have not yet written code to convert the inputted csv file to an array. Once I do, I will use that instead of the sample quaternions.

The problem is that when I run the program, the cube displays, but it does not rotate. I include enough sample quaternions to be able to observe the rotation, so lack of quaternions is not the issue. I get no console errors. I've tried including the line

```
renderer.render(scene,camera);
```

within the rotate function and at several other locations in the code, but that did not re-render the cube.

What code should I include in the animate function to re-render the cube after each quaternion is applied? Or, is there a way to execute the same task with requestAnimationFrame?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is, you need to use the `renderer.render(scene,camera);` inside the `rotate` function because after changing the cube's orientation, you need to re-render the scene.

The second thing is, you are using the `setTimeout` function in a wrong way. You want to call the rotate function after each of 16.7, 33.4, 50.1 ... milliseconds. So you have to pass the time that way. Also you have to pass a callback function instead of directly calling the function. Try this following code -

```
let time = 0;
 for(let i=0; i<quat_data.length; i++) {
     time += 16.7;
     setTimeout(function() { 
         rotate(quat_data[i])
     }, time);
 }
```

The last thing is, try to avoid `setTimeout` function for animation, instead use `window.requestAnimationFrame`. This function will be called by the browser before the next repaint and you can change the cube orientation in this function and render the scene. Here is the sample code -

```
let i= 0;
var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    i++;
    if (i >= quat_data.length)
        i = quat_data.length - 1;

    let quat = quat_data[i];
    cube.applyQuaternion(quat);

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
};

animate();
```